# Mute Video in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Safari doesn't support the mute attribute in a video tag. So the following video will not be muted in Safari:

```
<video id="video" width="180" autoplay="true" muted="true"></video>
```

How can a video be muted in Safari?

Comment: The muted attribute works just fine for me in Safari: https://jsfiddle.net/n4re4eh4/

Comment: On iphones, ipads, ipods safari don't let javascript change the volume!

Comment: @DOCTYPEHTML do you have javascript enabled??